# Word for controlled/controlled through use of laws by the government

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, verbs

y'all I'm writing about sexuality. In one sentence I am speaking about how the government can directly control sexuality through the use of laws and I'm trying to find the right word. This is the sentence as it is right now (it's not a complete sentence).

"So often, sexuality is *legislated* by the government..."

Right now I'm using the word legislated but I'm not sure if it's right for this context or if it can be used in this way. I had little luck finding clarity about that online.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the reason for not using the obvious *controlled by the law*? Note, incidentally, that *by the law* makes it unnecessary to say *by the government*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest *regulated*. A "regulation" is

> A rule of order having the force of law, prescribed by a superior or competent authority, relating to the actions of those under the authority's control.

https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Government+regulation

(googling "regulated sexuality" comes up with lots of relevant hits ...)

Comment: Thank you! This is actually the word I was looking for. It was on the tip of my tongue.